# Why am I being redirected to some other page even though the from property in state has a value in react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to build a website and I'm using react router to accomplish that. Thing is that I have this page with the "/carrito" path, that should be available in the navbar from all parts of the app. Whenever you enter this path, I want that, when you press the back arrow in the browser, the app redirects you to the "/inicio" path.

I tried that by using the useNavigate hook:

```
<button
    type="button"
    className="cart"
    onClick={() => {
        navigate("/carrito", {
            replace: true,
            state: { from: "/inicio" },
        });
}}>
```

The thing is that for some reason, when I press the go back button from the browser, it redirects me to the "" path. I really don't understand what's happening

Comment: Back navigations are just that, navigate back, a.k.a. POP to the path you were last on. They won't navigate anywhere else. If you want to do this then you need to PUSH or REPLACE to a new path. Can you [edit] the post to clarify what you are trying to do, and what the exact issue is in better detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using navigate("/bla", { replace: true, ... }), you replace the last item in the stack with "/bla". In case "" (or "/") was the page before "/inicio" this should be correct.

To get your desired behaviour try calling navigate twice like:

```js
navigate("/inicio") // maybe with { replace: true }?
navigate("/carrito")
```

Not sure if this works tho. And it will add two additional items to the stack

Comment: This solution works, thanks, but how can I achieve the same without adding the 2 items to the stack?